# I'm applying for a study permit in Canada at the port of entry. What country do I list as the country where I'm applying?

Tags: immigration, canada, student-visa, usa

I'm a US citizen applying for a study permit in Canada at the port of entry, when I arrive in Canada. The application, which I am completing ahead of time, asks for the "country or territory where applying," as well as my status in that country and "from" and "to" dates.

Should I indicate that I am applying from the U.S. or Canada?

Second, if I indicate I am applying from Canada, what should I indicate as my current status (visitor, student, or other)? And what should I list in the "from" and "to" dates? Would this be the length of time I intend to remain in Canada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, at the point you are applying (at the border), you would not really be *in* Canada (as you don't have any visitor or residence status in Canada).

Just put USA and since you're a US citizen too, they'll just skip right over that part. After all, you'll be standing right in front of the officer, it'll be obvious to them where you are. They won't deny you on such a trivial technicality.